# search in collection with lowercase - xquery

Tags: string, xquery, lowercase

I'm looking for a way to search through a collection comparing elements of nodes with the lower-case function. the thing is that what i've tried does not work:

here is a very simple query that i built but it doesn't return anything:

```
let $valor2 := lower-case(request:get-parameter('valor2',''))
let $contribuciones := collection('final/contribuciones/')/Contribucion[lower-case(Aporte) = $valor2]
```

however `$contribuciones` appear to be empty

I don't think the XML is important in this question but here is an example of it:

```
<Contribuciones>
   <Contribucion>
       <id> 1243243435 </id>
       <Aporte> something </Aporte>
   </Contribucion>
</Contribuciones>
```

What i want to do is receive a parameter and store it in a variable, then search in a collection for the nodes that have the exact parameter in an element (in this case Aporte) ignoring any case.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that `count(collection('final/contribuciones/')/Contribucion)` is not 0?

Comment: Does the Aporte element really contain the whitespace around "something"? Probably `$valor2` will not. If so, wrap access to it in `normalize-space(...)`.

Comment: yeah the collection returns 20 nodes and about the space it's a mistake there's no whitespace in the Aporte element

Comment: Try casting valor2 to string.

Comment: $valor2 is ok, i don't know why but /Contribucion[lower-case(Aporte)] is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be

```
collection('final/contribuciones/')//Contribucion
```

The collection() function returns the document nodes - not the root element of each document.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference for my case, the collection function works fine.